# Delete XML by listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Trying to delete node by id (
Example: if i chose to delete the "data" node with the id 1.), but get NULL. cant figure why.

Dont sure even if i on the right way.

I success to display the data, but after click on delete button - get null.

## ASPX

```
<asp:ListView OnItemDeleting="del" runat="server" ID="LV_data" DataSourceID="XDS_data">
<ItemTemplate>
<h2><asp:Label ID="LBL_number" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("id") %>'></asp:Label></h2>
<asp:TextBox Width="300"  CssClass="ltr" runat="server" ID="TB_small1" Text='<%# XPath("small_image_url") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox Width="300" CssClass="ltr" runat="server" ID="TB_big1" Text='<%#XPath("big_image_url") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB_title1" Text='<%#XPath("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="del"  OnClick="del" Text="delete" />

    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XDS_data" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/AM_data.xml" XPath="/Data/datas/data">
    </asp:XmlDataSource>
```

## C#

```
protected void del(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));

    Label lbl_id = (Label)LV_data.FindControl("LBL_number");

        doc.Root.Element("datas").Element("data")
       .Descendants("id")
       .Where(l => l.Value == lbl_id.Text)
       .Select(x => x.Parent)
       .Remove();

       doc.Save(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));

}
```

## XML

```
<Data>
 <datas>
    <data>
      <id>1</id>
      <small_image_url>~/imgs/small_cake_data.png</small_image_url>
      <title>My title</title>
      <big_image_url>~/imgs/data_top.jpg</big_image_url>
    </data>
    <data>
      <id>2</id>
      <small_image_url>~/imgs/small_cake_data.png</small_image_url>
      <title>My title</title>
      <big_image_url>~/imgs/data_top.jpg</big_image_url>
    </data>
  </datas>
<Data>
```

The null is for the line of c# : .Where(l => l.Value == lbl_id.Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button CommandArgument='<%#XPath("id") %>' runat="server" CommandName="del"  OnClick="del" Text="Delete" />


    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
    Button myButton = (Button)sender;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.CommandArgument.ToString());
    XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("Data/datas/data[id='" + i + "']");
    if (el != null) { el.ParentNode.RemoveChild(el); }

    doc.Save(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the NullReferenceException is because the Label cannot be identified this way:

```
Label lbl_id = (Label)LV_data.FindControl("LBL_number");
```

The FindControl is run on the ListView so that there are several labels with the respective id, one for each item in the ListView.

In order to solve this, I'd suggest the following: Instead of using a click event handler, handle the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event for the ListView. Then you can identify the item that the button was clicked in and execute FindControl for this item.